# How big is the performance loss when printing a progress information via carriage return in C#?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm using DotNetZip for unpacking an archive with lots of little documents (about 100,000). I want the user to know what progress has been made so far so I print a percentaged information while unpacking the archive.

Now which of the following two solutions is appreciated concerning performance?

**1:** print output on each 500th item, need to have a modulo operation

```
double i = 0;
double size = zip.Count
foreach(ZipEntry element in zip)
{
    if(i % 500 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("\rInstalling "+ name +"... "+ (i/size)*100 +"%");
        Console.Out.Flush();
    }
    element.Extract(destinationPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    i++;
}
```

**2:** print output every item

```
double i = 0;
double size = zip.Count
foreach(ZipEntry element in zip)
{
    Console.Write("\rInstalling "+ name +"... "+ (i/size)*100 +"%");
    Console.Out.Flush();

    element.Extract(destinationPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and measure each option?

Comment: Every time I see a performance question, I feel the need for people to read this http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: As a user I would not be annoyed by 100.000 prompts on my console, most of them telling me it has not progressed since last prompt. So independantly from the performance question I'd prompt only if the progress rate changes significantly, each 10% for example.

Comment: A quick test (not even extracting zip files) yields 7.6 s to write 100k messages to the Console and 2.3 minutes to write 100k files. So we're talking about a difference of about 5%, at most. Maybe your users care about that, maybe they don't, we don't know. You've got to do the same experiment in a realistic user scenario. We don't know what that is and we can't tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Stopwatch (System.Diagnostics) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check the difference like this:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

double i = 0;
double size = zip.Count
foreach(ZipEntry element in zip)
{
    if(i % 500 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write("\rInstalling "+ name +"... "+ (i/size)*100 +"%");
        Console.Out.Flush();
    }
    element.Extract(destinationPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
    i++;
}

stopWatch.Stop();

MessageBox.Show(stopWatch.ElapsedTicks.ToString()); //Or milliseconds ,...
```

then compare the two different codes.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this sort of progress before.  I'd add a time variable.  No point in output of progress faster than the eye can see.  Since each file copy time can vary, do something like:

```
time_t timelast = time();
time_t timenow;

if ((i % 500) == 0) {
    timenow = time();
    if ((timenow - timelast) >= 1) {
        timelast = timenow;
        // do output
    }
}
```

The `time()` may be a little rough so you could consider higher resolution sources.  You might even eliminate the `i` variable altogether.  Usually, progress output at 1 second intervals is good enough and doesn't usally impact performance too much.